# Как избежать 504 Gateway Time-out php

Tags: php

504 Gateway Time-out ошибка происходит при выполнении высоко-нагруженного скрипта, как можно оптимизировать работу что-бы избежать таких ошибок?

Например у меня многомерный массив и я делаю занесение его в базу, в массиве около 1000 записей.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://site.com?getprice');
$obj_prices = json_decode($json);
 // формируем массив
 foreach ($obj_prices as $key=>$objr) {
   $objects2[$objr->WARES_GROUP_ID][] = $objr;
 }

foreach($objects2 as $key=>$obj) {
   $db->query("INSERT INTO price SET p = ".$obj->p.", s = ".$obj->s);
}
```

Comment: `set_time_limit()` пробовали? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php. Это даст скрипту возможность работать дольше. Но если надо именно оптимизировать, то приведите весь скрипт - без кода скрипта оптимизировать не возможно

Comment: @cyadvert не помогло... поставил на 600, мне кажется памяти не хватает

Comment: ну поставьте побольше...90000... :) просто чтобы убедиться, что скрипт вообще до конца доходит... Может там петля какая вечная... Но без кода помогать в опптимизации можно лишь теоретически...

Comment: @cyadvert добавил код в вопрос.. возможно это из-за исерта в базу данных, может как-то оптимизировать обращения к базе

Comment: @modelfak, не надо 1000 запросов INSERT делать в каждом по 1 записи. Нужно сделать 1 запрос INSERT добавив им сразу 1000 записей.

Comment: @Visman думаете это будет производительней? ну да в принципе меньше будет ожиданий на выполнение

Comment: Не стоит выполнять что-то высоконагруженное в скриптах, запускаемых через браузер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант оптимизации наверное имеет смысл переписать код внесения в базу.
Сделать не один запрос для каждой записи, а заносить группами.
Т.е. не `INSERT INTO ... SET ...`, а лучше `INSERT INTO [table_name] ([fields]) VALUES ([values1]), ([values2]), ([values3])` и т.д.
Т.е. в вашем случае

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO price (p, s) VALUES ";
foreach($objects2 as $key=>$obj) {
   $sql .= "(".$obj->p.", ".$obj->s . "),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
$db->query($sql);
```

В связи с тем, что у вас более тысячи записей, наверное не стоит делать один запрос с тысячью `values`. Можеть разбить и добавлять по сотням?... Это уже имеет смысл протестировать